# mysql join three tables error with cross join

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to get some details not in ratings table with user name and i made a cross join query. but it shows me syntax error

```
SELECT applications.reference as "User id", applications.id
FROM applications
cross join ratings where (applications.id) NOT IN ( SELECT ratings.application_id FROM ratings )
INNER JOIN ratings ON users.id=ratings.user_id
```

error shows

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN ratings ON users.id=ratings.user_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2
```

i want to get user details in applications where not in ratings table with user name in users table. how can i fix this?

Comment: The error message doesn't even match the query you posted.  At this point, you should include sample data for all tables involved, and then show us what the expected output is.

Comment: @Pavan Kumar T S  where should i add ON to query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need such a query :

```
SELECT a.reference as "User id", a.id
  FROM applications a
 CROSS JOIN ratings r
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = r.user_id 
 WHERE a.id != r.application_id;
```

Comment: is this can sort not in

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga you're welcome. I think you want to ask for `!=` with `join`  could be replace with your subquery with `not in`. Yes.

Comment: yes but this query shows me in phpmyadmin error "column 'r.application_id' in 'where clause"

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga that's an excerpt from `SELECT ratings.application_id FROM ratings`, so there's a column `application_id` of `ratings`of which I aliased as `r`...

Answer (score 0):

SELECT applications.reference as "User id", applications.id
FROM applications
INNER JOIN ratings ON users.id=ratings.user_id
cross join ratings where (applications.id) NOT IN ( SELECT ratings.application_id FROM ratings )

Comment: From review: could you please detail out your question a bit more?